# scrapy request not working

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm scraping each information from [here](http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html?term=australia&maxitems=25&nvcnt=4&nvsls=[5;10L&nvloc=0&nvemp=[11;49]) using `selenium` and `Scrapy`.

I need to go through every company name and as i reach the company information page, i need to extract the information from company information page as well as i need to open the **Marketing Contacts** page and extract information from there too. `Scrapy's Requests` opens the company information page but it does not work when i try to open the **Marketing Contacts** page.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
import time

class HooverSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "hspider"
    allowed_domains = ["hoovers.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/company-search.html?term=australia&maxitems=25&nvcnt=4&nvsls=[5;10L&nvloc=0&nvemp=[11;49]"] #hloru




    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3)
        company = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="cmp-company-directory"]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/a')
        links = []
        for c in company:
            links.append(c.get_attribute('href'))
        for link in links:
            yield Request(str(link),self.parse_link)


     def parse_link(self,response):

        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(2)

        if (self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="left-content"]/h1').text):
            title = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="left-content"]/h1').text
        else:
            title = ''

        print title


        if (self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="left-content"]/p/span[1]').text):
            street = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="left-content"]/p/span[1]').text
        else:
            street = ''
        print street

        marketing = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fs-comps-A"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
        print marketing
        return Request(marketing,self.parse_page)

 #this one is not working
    def parse_page(self,response):
        print response.url
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3)
        print 'hello'
```

This code works though.

```
class HooverSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "hspider"
    allowed_domains = ["hoovers.com"]

    start_urls = ["http://www.hoovers.com/company-information/cs/marketing-lists.LAFFORT_AUSTRALIA_PTY_LIMITED.3d01c1d98ad9322f.html"]

    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        time.sleep(3)
        marketing = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="fs-comps-A"]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/ul[2]/li[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
        return Request(marketing,callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self,response):

        print 'hh'
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is in the way you are getting the "Marketing Contacts" link. I'd use [`find_element_by_link_text()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_link_text) instead to locate the link by the "Marketing Contacts" link text.

Also, few things to note here:

- you cannot use the same driver instance (`self.driver`) in different Scrapy methods/callbacks - Scrapy is completely asynchronous and you'll quickly get into situation where two methods would be conflicting trying to reuse the same driver instance and, hence, a browser window
- use [Explicit Waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html#explicit-waits) instead of hardcoded time delays with `time.sleep()`
- make sure you really need selenium for parsing all of the pages starting from search results through a company profile and to marketing contacts

Here is what worked for me:

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
from scrapy.http import Request

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

class HooverSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "hspider"

    ...

    def parse_link(self, response):
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        driver.get(response.url)

        marketing = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Marketing Contacts")))
        marketing_link = marketing.get_attribute('href')
        driver.close()

        yield Request(marketing_link, self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        print "HERE!"
        print response.url
        print "-----------"
```

If you do need `selenium` here, think about using a headless `PhantomJS` instead of `Firefox` - could at least improve the performance and make it work in a displayless environment (replace `webdriver.Firefox()` with `webdriver.PhantomJS()`).